# Delphi xe Android send email with attachment image file not found or can not open

Tags: android, email, delphi

i want to send an email with text and image jpg in the path DCIM/Saved Photos/demm.jpg, but in the email inbox just recieved a text only. And When i hit email2 button my program showing file not found or can not open file...

here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.email2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SMTP: TIdSMTP;
  Email: TIdMessage;
  SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  Attachment : TIdAttachment;
  atFile : String;
begin
  atFile :=  System.IOUtils.TPath.GetCameraPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim   + 'Saved Photos/demm.jpg';       {System.IOUtils.TPath.GetCameraPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim + '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/1/files/DCIM/"Saved Photos"/demm.jpg';  }
  SMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  Email := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

  try
    SSLHandler.MaxLineAction := maException;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

    SMTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
    SMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    SMTP.Port := 587;
    SMTP.Username := 'myemail@gmail.com';
    SMTP.Password := 'mypass';
    SMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

    Email.From.Address := 'myemail@gmail.com' ;
    Email.Recipients.EmailAddresses := 'targetemail@yahoo.com';
    Email.Subject := 'Notifikasi';
    Email.Body.Text := 'Kuruma no naka de hito ga imasu!!!';
    if FileExists(atFile) then
      begin
          Attachment := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(Email.MessageParts,atFile);   {'/sdcard/DCIM/"Saved Photos"/demm.jpg'}
      end
    else
      begin
          ShowMessage('File Not Found or Could not Open.');
      end;


    SMTP.Connect;
    SMTP.Send(Email);
    SMTP.Disconnect;

  finally
    Attachment.Free;
    SMTP.Free;
    Email.Free;
    SSLHandler.Free;
  end;
  hidepopup;
end;
```

please help me??
sorry for my bad english

Comment: Smells like permission problems.

Comment: hi ..@Turrican ,what permission must i use to fix my code above??

Comment: 'my program showing file not found or can not open file...'. If your own app cannot find or open it then it makes no sense trying to mail it. Do you really mean this message: ' ShowMessage('File Not Found or Could not Open.');' ?

Comment: '{'/sdcard/DCIM/"Saved Photos"/demm.jpg'}'. Do you mean {'/sdcard/DCIM/Saved Photos/demm.jpg'} ?

Comment: yes,,thats what i mean

Comment: Also here at the end of your code you are calling .Free if you say this is running on Andriod then it is using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) and this the .Free calls do not free the object but simply sets it to NIL if the  object still however holds a strong reference  to another member you will run into memory leaks

Comment: okay :) ,,,thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are refering to a picture saved in your main DCIM camera folder on your andriod then simply replace

```
atFile :=  System.IOUtils.TPath.GetCameraPath
```

With

```
atFile :=  System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedCameraPath
```

Also include in your uses:

```
System.IOUtils
```

because you error clearly states that it can't find the file.
GetCameraPath will point towards your DCIM folder in your com.andriod.project folder
where GetSharedCameraPath points towards your common camera folder